# JToolTip on JPanel mouseMove action

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtooltip

I've trying to create a `JToolTip` over a `JPanel`. The idea is, that user move over the J`Panel (mouseMove)` and behind the cursor will be the tooltip. But I dont know, how to set up tooltip to `JPanel`. I mean, that I create instance of `JToolTip`, `setLocation` by cursor (in `mouseMove`) and then I don't know how to set up this new tooltip to panel (like `JPanel.setToolTip(newJToolTip)`).

Comment: *"Thanks for ideas."*  Ask an explicit question, and add a '?' to the end.

Comment: To make your question constructive better and sooner provide the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a tooltip on a `JPanel` using `setToolTipText()`. When the mouse cursor stops, the tooltip is displayed. If you no longer need this behavior, just call the method again with `null` as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for answer,
but I exactly need behaviour, that tooltip'll be right behind the cursor when its moving. Because I am painting on this panel and I need this tooltip show only on specific coords (for instance over a couple of rectangles).

Comment: Listen for mouseMove events and check if the mouse location is inside your rectangles, call the setTooltipText method with a String parameter, otherwise with null.